# What's wrong with asking 'homework' questions?

Tags: discussion

I've seen some questions before by people just getting into programming or a language that get downvoted/closed with the reason being that they're 'homework' questions and that they should have tried first themselves.

But, if they don't have any experience they might just not know how to do something, so they couldn't try it themselves first.

Comment: It is not homework *per se* that is the issue. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, we help those that have done their research and tried to solve the problem themselves *first*. That applies to homework or any other coding problem. If you post a homework question with a *good faith effort* to solve it yourself we can help still.

Comment: Homework questions are ok. Work orders are not.

Comment: From Meta.Programmers.SE: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/40980)

Comment: *Who gets homework not based on their course of study?*  Pay attention in class, read your coursework, and you shouldn't be in this position.  In some respects, students have an easier time of it--we get people who simply dump their requirements and ask others to implement them.  Students at least have resources to guide their work...

Comment: All to often, even when there is code, there is no aparrent attempt at debugging.  Why profs/TA give out assignments that are woefully beyond the abilities of students to debug is beyond me.  Then again, it's much easier to get/.con SO contributors to do the heavy-lifting of getting stuff working as desired than plough through the code with a debugger and/or logger.  So, profs/TA/students, get your acts together, please!

Comment: Finding out how to do stuff when you don't already know is intrinsic to uni education.   Students should get off their asses and actually learn stuff, not try to outsource their assignments, and profs should not ask students to write clients/servers when, after posting their stuff to SO and getting comments, they comment back 'what is a debugger and where can I get one?'

Answer (score 22):

Nothing.

There's a lot wrong with "do my work for me" questions though.

Just because something is a homework problem doesn't invalidate it as a question, provided the asker is following the guidance in ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make a good question. The source of it is irrelevant.

However, it's often the case that "homework" questions aren't "good questions" - and these should be downvoted or closed *because* they're bad questions, not because they're homework.